# How to get the position of a Coordinate with respect to Mouse position?

Tags: c#, wpf, logic, coordinates

I am on Wpf and I have a list of coordinates where I draw them on a Bitmap Image. My Bitmap file is `1000 * 1000` and it gets filled in a `680 * 440` Image control. Now what I am trying to accomplish is to highlight the coordinates that are near the mouse cursor, when mouse is hoovering my Image.

on `MouseMove()` event handler, I call this function and pass to it my mouse position with respect to the Image control:

```
public void HighLightNearbyDots(Point MousePosition)
{
    int Distance;
    CoordPoint temp = new CoordPoint();
    temp.X = MousePosition.X;
    temp.Y = MousePosition.Y;

    foreach (var point in myDisplayedCoords)
    {
        Distance = (int)(temp - point); // using subtraction operator that I wrote

        if (Distance < 10)
        {
            point.Color = Colors.Blue;
        }
        else
        {
            point.Color = InitialCoordColor; // Aqua
        }
    }

    DrawImage();
}
```

Yes I redraw my image on every call to reflect the changes. Maybe the issue is that I need to scale or calculate some ratio between the `1000 * 1000` file size and the `680 * 440` control size to hit the exact pixel.. But I am not sure what is the issue. Below is the current result which is killing me since the morning. Could any one help me approach that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [How to scale a coordinate system?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1860470/how-to-scale-a-coordinate-system) Now we know the equation. Then I use it this way:

```
int Distance;
CoordPoint temp = new CoordPoint();
temp.X = MousePosition.X / 660 * Bitmap.Width;
temp.Y = Bitmap.Height - (MousePosition.Y / 440 * Bitmap.Height); // y is flipped
```

[image]