# How can I get "thinner" graph for my coordinate system?

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, logic

Following up with [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400410/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-coordinate-with-respect-to-mouse-position), I have a bunch of coordinates and I draw them on a bitmap image as a coordinate system. Now, I would like to get rid of all the noise, and filter coordinates to give a "clearer" or "cleaner" path and "less" or "better" data to work on. To explain more, I will need to expose my **awesome** *painting* skills as follows:

**Current:**

[image]

**Desired:**

[image]

Notice:

- I will need to delete coordinates
- I might need to add coordinates
- I might need to ignore shortest neighbor in some cases

The only thing I can think of, is to use a shortest path algorithm such as [**A***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) and [**Dijkstra**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). And populate data in some sort of data structure to contain neighbors and costs for every node and then to execute the algorithm. I don't want to start something that might be wrong or waste. I would love to see a pseudo code if possible on **how could I solve such a problem**?

P.S I am currently on Wpf C# but I am open to use C# or C++ for any task. Thanks

Comment: That's an interesting problem. It looks like you are either trying to do curve fitting, or optimization. In the latter case, my suggestion is: try to formulate a metric by which a candidate output gets a score (for example, sum of shortest distances from the input to the output) and then let loose an evolutionary algorithm. I'd be surprised if that didn't work well.

Comment: My first though is to just do a least-squares (or other) best fit to your input data. Then for the output data you can have it only plot data points that are closest to the least-squares line. You probably have to define what is "right" and "wrong" and what is and isn't a "waste". If it's all for display purposes then it sort of doesn't matter, but if you are for example running some sort of statistical analysis on the output data then I'm sure what is a "correct" transformation is strictly defined (in which case, find and follow those definitions).

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen Thanks! Please allow me some time to research that

Comment: Please give a general and precise specification of possible inputs and desired outputs. That one example is not sufficient.

Comment: @Raphael Will do. Thanks for pointing that out. I will draw some other sample. And I changed the title (this is better?). The general idea though it is that I have a cloud of coordinates, which make a path shape. I want to "clean" the shape and keep the minimal needed possible. I am talking about hundred of thousand of points (maybe 2k per second on reading). So I would need an algorithm to "_Get Rid_", "_Curve Fit_" or/and "_Thin_" the overall cloud of points (shape). I don't care (a lot) of the execution time since it is going to happen only once on all the million (~) points.

Comment: It would be nice to include how far points must go to be considered noise, if this is curve how smooth or based on what it should be. How do you gather input? What are avg sizes? (If this is the max some heavy methods, but looking nice are available)... Until then it is like PacMan Xmas tree.

Comment: Don't you also have a sample number along with the x,y value? If that's the case, you could start very simple and create running averages of a couple of samples for each coordinate.

Comment: Maybe Ramer Douglas Peucker algorithm? I hope that you are not counting on implementation in given language but rather on algorithms (known or modified to fit). A star or Dijkstra does not seem right, even simple floodfill with dilation (or skeletonization) will do better job, but still it is a bit underspecified.

Comment: @JohanLundberg what do you mean by a sample number? My class `CoordPoint` has just a `x`, a `y` and a `color`

Comment: @Quantic what do you men by least-squares? Could you clarify with sample points? Please and thanks

Comment: @Evil I imagine that I would be able to control "_how far points must go to be considered noise_" but 3 units away from the "school of points" or the "virtual predicted final result line" should be fair. Also the curve is based on current points. So I have points already and if you zoom in you see "noisy" distributed nodes and if you zoom out you see a shape (almost a line). I want to get rid of the "micro noise". I gather input by taking distance from a moving advanced sensor to a fixed wall.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphological_skeleton, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinning_(morphology) and see if they do what you want.

Comment: [Also posted on CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/60848/755).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after is a path finding application.  There are several ways to approach this, but one of the simpler ways is to:

```
Pick a starting point, add to list
While True:
    For each border_pt bordering last point on list:
        Count number of points bordering border_pt
        If count > best_count:
            Mark border_pt as best

    if border_pt is empty:
        break

    Add border_pt to list
```

Here's some C# code that does just that, it generates a simple list based on your cloud:

[image: Final path]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class ExampleProgram : Form
    {
        const int GridWidth = 24;
        const int GridHeight = 15;

        List<Point> m_points = new List<Point>();
        List<Point> m_trail = new List<Point>();

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new ExampleProgram());
        }

        ExampleProgram()
        {
            // Simple little tool to add a bunch of points
            AddPoints(
                0, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5,
                6, 4, 5, 4, 7, 4, 7, 3, 8, 3, 8, 4, 8, 5, 8, 6, 9, 6, 9, 5, 9, 4, 9, 3, 10, 2,
                10, 3, 10, 4, 10, 5, 10, 6, 11, 5, 11, 4, 11, 3, 11, 2, 12, 4, 12, 5, 13, 5,
                13, 6, 13, 8, 14, 8, 14, 7, 14, 6, 15, 7, 15, 8, 15, 9, 14, 9, 14, 10, 13, 10,
                12, 10, 11, 10, 13, 11, 14, 11, 15, 11, 15, 12, 16, 12, 17, 12, 18, 12, 19,
                12, 18, 11, 17, 11, 17, 10, 18, 10, 19, 10, 19, 9, 19, 8, 20, 8, 21, 8, 18,
                7, 19, 7, 20, 7, 21, 7, 21, 6, 22, 6, 23, 6, 21, 5, 20, 5, 19, 5, 19, 4, 18,
                4, 17, 4, 20, 3, 21, 3, 22, 3, 20, 2, 19, 2, 18, 2, 19, 1, 20, 1, 21, 1, 19,
                0, 18, 0, 10, 0, 4, 1);

            // Very basic form logic
            ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(GridWidth * 20, GridHeight * 20);
            DoubleBuffered = true;
            Paint += ExampleProgram_Paint;

            // Add a new point to the form (commented out)
            // MouseUp += ExampleProgram_MouseUp_AddPoint;

            // Draw the trail we find
            MouseUp += ExampleProgram_MouseUp_AddTrail;

            // Pick a starting point to start finding the trail from
            // TODO: Left as an excersize for the reader to decide how to pick
            // the starting point programatically
            m_trail.Add(new Point(0, 4));

        }

        IEnumerable<Point> Border(Point pt)
        {
            // Return all points that border a give point

            if (pt.X > 0)
            {
                if (pt.Y > 0)
                {
                    yield return new Point(pt.X - 1, pt.Y - 1);
                }
                yield return new Point(pt.X - 1, pt.Y);
                if (pt.Y < GridHeight - 1)
                {
                    yield return new Point(pt.X - 1, pt.Y + 1);
                }
            }
            if (pt.Y > 0)
            {
                yield return new Point(pt.X, pt.Y - 1);
            }
            if (pt.Y < GridHeight - 1)
            {
                yield return new Point(pt.X, pt.Y + 1);
            }

            if (pt.X < GridWidth - 1)
            {
                if (pt.Y > 0)
                {
                    yield return new Point(pt.X + 1, pt.Y - 1);
                }
                yield return new Point(pt.X + 1, pt.Y);
                if (pt.Y < GridHeight - 1)
                {
                    yield return new Point(pt.X + 1, pt.Y + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        void AddPoints(params int[] points)
        {
            // Helper to add a bunch of points to our list of points
            for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i += 2)
            {
                m_points.Add(new Point(points[i], points[i + 1]));
            }
        }

        void ExampleProgram_MouseUp_AddTrail(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Calculate the trail
            while (true)
            {
                // Find the best point for the next point
                int bestCount = 0;
                Point best = new Point();

                // At the current end point, test all the points around it
                foreach (var pt in Border(m_trail[m_trail.Count - 1]))
                {
                    // And for each point, see how many points this point borders
                    int count = 0;
                    if (m_points.Contains(pt) && !m_trail.Contains(pt))
                    {
                        foreach (var test in Border(pt))
                        {
                            if (m_points.Contains(test))
                            {
                                if (m_trail.Contains(test))
                                {
                                    // This is a point both in the original cloud, and the current
                                    // trail, so give it a negative weight
                                    count--;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // We haven't visited this point, so give it a positive weight
                                    count++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (count > bestCount)
                    {
                        // This point looks better than anything we've found, so 
                        // it's the best one so far
                        bestCount = count;
                        best = pt;
                    }
                }

                if (bestCount <= 0)
                {
                    // We either didn't find anything, or what we did find was bad, so
                    // break out of the loop, we're done
                    break;
                }

                m_trail.Add(best);
            }

            Invalidate();
        }

        void ExampleProgram_MouseUp_AddPoint(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Just add the point, and dump it out
            int x = (int)Math.Round((((double)e.X) - 10.0) / 20.0, 0);
            int y = (int)Math.Round((((double)e.Y) - 10.0) / 20.0, 0);
            m_points.Add(new Point(x, y));
            Debug.WriteLine("m_points.Add(new Point(" + x + ", " + y + "));");
            Invalidate();
        }

        void ExampleProgram_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Simple drawing, just draw a grid, and the points
            e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);

            for (int x = 0; x < GridWidth; x++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, x * 20 + 10, 0, x * 20 + 10, ClientSize.Height);
            }

            for (int y = 0; y < GridHeight; y++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, y * 20 + 10, ClientSize.Width, y * 20 + 10);
            }

            foreach (var pt in m_points)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, (pt.X * 20 + 10) - 5, (pt.Y * 20 + 10) - 5, 10, 10);
            }

            foreach (var pt in m_trail)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, (pt.X * 20 + 10) - 6, (pt.Y * 20 + 10) - 6, 12, 12);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Anon this looks extremely helpful and might save the day. Please allow me some time to absorb it

Comment: Hi Anon I am trying to compile your code. I am getting couple errors could you help me please? [**See here as GIF**](https://giphy.com/gifs/c-code-26BRtkerL162SFAQ0)

Comment: You need `using System.Diagnostics;` like in my example.  As for the second error, no clue.  Did you add another `ExampleProgram()` constructor?  My code is meant to be dropped in, as is, to a single source file and compiled without any changes at all.

Comment: I did not copy paste the whole thing, my bad :) Removing `public ExampleProgram()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }` fixed it now and it worked like a charm! Thank you for helping appreciate it!

Comment: I am impressed with how the input data is exactly mine and with your painting skills as well ;) "_// Simple little tool to add **a bunch of points**_" Hats off @Anon

Comment: Thanks very much :)

Comment: So.. I just finished integrating your masterpiece with my humble system. Had to tune and do some detailing like `.Contain` did not work and changing `while(true)` to another condition "_while current is not the last_". It worked smooth and nice and all is good. How can I be like you? :))

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for an operation called *thinning* or *skeletonization*, possibly followed by some post-processing to remove small components. There are different algorithms for this that offer different properties. For example [Guo and Hall's](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=62074) and [Zhang and Suen's](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=358023).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider treating your coordinates as a binary image and apply some [Morphological techniques](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/ImageProcessing-html/topic4.htm) to the image.

[Thinning](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/thin.htm) might give you good results, but processing like this can be tricky to get working well in a wide range of cases.

Comment: Interesting, I am looking at [Thinning](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/thin.htm) and Figure 2 is similar to what I am trying to achieve. But "_treat my coordinates as a binary image_" I need to think how to do that