# How can I find the "thinner" path from a cloud of coordinates?

Tags: algorithm, graphics

Following up with [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400410/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-coordinate-with-respect-to-mouse-position), I have a bunch of coordinates and I draw them on a bitmap image as a coordinate system. Now, I would like to get rid of all the noise, and filter coordinates to give a "clearer" or "cleaner" path and "less" or "better" data to work on. To explain more, I will need to expose my **awesome** *painting* skills as follows:

**Current:**

[image]

**Desired:**

[image]

Notice:

- I might need to delete coordinates
- I might need to add coordinates
- I might need to ignore shortest neighbor in some cases

The only thing I can think of, is to use a shortest path algorithm such as [**A***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) and [**Dijkstra**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). And populate data in some sort of data structure to contain neighbors and costs from every node and then to execute the algorithm. I don't want to start something that might be wrong or waste. I would love to see a pseudo code if possible on **how could I solve such a problem**?